# What can I learn about English pragmatics from this dialogue?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Charles : How do you do, my name is Charles.

> Guest : Don't be ridiculous, Charles died 20 years ago!

> Charles : Must be a different Charles, I think.

> Guest : Are you telling me I don't know my own brother?

> Charles : No, no.

> (Four weddings and a funeral, 1994)

I'm quoting the above dialogue from *Pragmatics And The English Language, Jonathan Culpeper & Michael Haugh*. The authors use the text to explain the concept of deixis, definiteness, and anaphora. Below is a part of the explanation about the dialogue.

> The crux of the guest's confusion here is the guest has his brother in mind when *Charles* is referred to, and consequently thinks that Charles does as well.

Here are my questions:

1. How can it be that upon hearing the name *Charles*, the guest relates only to his brother who died 20 years ago? Is the guest really ignorant of the fact that there can be many people by the name of *Charles* apart from his brother who passed away 20 years ago?
2. Is there some sort of humour behind such assumption made by the guest?

I lack pragmatic competence in English language. Please help!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The book is incorrect to say the guest is confused. The guest is joking and understands exactly what they're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was (and was intended to be) funny precisly because a sensible person would know that there are other people named "Charles", and particularly because the guest's brother is dead, the guest should know that the person introducing himself **must** be a different Charles.

This passage reminds me a bit of the much longer and much funnier sketch ["Who's on First](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_on_First%3F)

Answer (score 3):

This conversation is absurd on purpose. Four Weddings and a Funeral is intended to be a funny movie and this is a silly interaction that would probably never happen in real life. It's 100% a joke. Your book is overexplaining the joke.